# How to make a two bar duevolte?

Tags: music, musixtex, musixper

How do I make a duevolte that repeats the two preceding bars, with a double diagonal line and a big "2" above it, like the right one in this image:

[image]

The left one is `\duevolte`, but I can't figure out how to get the right one...

As requested, a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{article}

\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixper

\begin{document}

\begin{music}
\setclefsymbol1{}\nostartrule\nobarnumbers\parindent0pt
\startpiece\addspace\afterruleskip
\Notes\qu{jjjj}\en\bar
\Notes\duevolte\en
\endpiece
\end{music}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm)

Comment: As far as I know `musixtex` (which provides `\duevolte`) doesn't have the two bar symbol.

Comment: Could you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing how to use `\duevolte`? Most users here won’t be familiar with `musitex`.

Comment: @doncherry: I don't think users not familiar with `musixtex` can help here, but there you go...

Comment: @kiw Thanks! One way or the other, it’s good practice here to provide a relevant MWE, if applicable. Since the symbols seem to be provided through a font, it might indeed be difficult to “fake” it (although I wouldn’t be surprised if one of our TikZ magicians came up with a `musixtex`-compatible solution). However, since it might not be too complicated for the developers of `musixtex` to create the two bar symbol based one the one with one bar, you could contact them. The system seems to be developed actively.

Comment: I went through (not manually though!) all 256 "characters" of `\musickeyfont` that `musictex` uses  and none of them match what you're looking for...

Answer (score 10):

Tinkering around, I came up with the following workaround

```
\notes\sk\rlap{\loffset{0.54}\duevolte}\rlap{\roffset{0.54}\duevolte}\en\ccharnote{u}{\sk\sk\bf\large2}\xbar\notes\sk\en
```

which yields

[image: fake two bar duevolte]

Looks pretty convincing, although the two bars could be a bit closer. But then again you would see the two extra dots. I don't know how well it plays with horizontal scaling/spacing but I'll use it for now.

The good thing is, there is an actual bar macro in there so it doesn't mess up the bar counting, although one would still need to suppress the bar numbering for that `\xbar`.

Comment: nice idea! :) You could say `\def\dduevolte{\rlap{\loffset{0.54}\duevolte}\rlap{\roffset{0.54}\duevolte}}` and then use `\dduevolte` for convenience if you need this more often.